# Docker with foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, foreman

Is there anyway to stop my container from exiting when running my Rails server with foreman. When foreman does its thing and starts up my rails server and sidekiq it immediately exits with exit code 0 as expected. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour and keep the container running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it still running after after running Rails and Sidekiq:

```
➜  ~  ps aux | grep foreman
maxd       2194   0.0  0.2  2486168  29004 s000  S+    2:09PM   0:00.56 foreman: master
```

Seems like foreman starts in foreground always. May be you problem doesn't related to foreman (try to check Rails and Sidekiq logs)? How are you running it in Docker container?

Comment: I am running it as such CMD ["bundle", "exec", "foreman", "start"] in my dockerfile and it seems to instantly exit. I am positive that it is not crashing and killing the container

Comment: Use [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#entrypoint) instead of CMD.

Comment: Has not made a difference. Still kills the container. I tried both ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec" ... ] and just ENTRYPOINT bundle exec ....

Comment: ok, but continue to use ENTRYPOINT because it is right way and provide your 1) Dockerfile 2) `docker log` of your container 3) output of `docker ps -a | grep <your container name>`

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. I just actually figured it out. Completely my fault of course. It was because I was deamonsing my processes in my Procfile.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem except I was running everything in the foreground.

`yarn build --watch` [works a bit differently](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1848) and it made the container to stop.

The solution was to use the `tty: true` option in the docker-compose file.

Maybe someone else will find this useful.